# Is Google adding Call extension data from Google Ads in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, data-transfer

Currently, I don't notice extension data like call data (start time, end time, ...) included in the data imported into BigQuery using Google Ads Transfer Service.

Is it planned to be included?

If yes .. when?

If no .. what's the reason for excluding it? Privacy? Raw data aggregation?

Comment: Please file a feature request with the relevant product team at Google instead. [Google Ads has a help page](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/176378?hl=en) where you can submit feedback, for instance.

Comment: Tried that ... but they mentioned to reach out to BigQuery support .. which I can't because I don't have a gold/platinum package :(